# Isabelle Logic simple natural deduction test

Tags: isabelle

http://pastebin.com/1ZEt9r32

What is wrong with line 30? Isabelle says this "Failed to finish proof⌂:
goal (2 subgoals):
 1. ¬ P ⟹ Q
 2. Q ⟹ ¬ P"

This is a theory for a natural deduction class

Answer (score 1):

The order of the premises is in the wrong order. If you reorder them as follows, then the proof is accepted.

```
from pq and npq and qq show "Q" by (rule disjE)
```

You can inspect the expected order by

```
thm disjE
```

Hope this helps,
René